# Remove all am/pm but the first instance in an array

Tags: php, arrays, time

I have an arrays of time slots in $a:

```
10:00 am,11:00 am,12:00 pm,01:00 pm,02:00 pm,03:00 pm,04:00 pm
```

I would like to remove all but the first instance of `am/pm` from the array:

```
10:00 am,11:00,12:00 pm,01:00 pm,02:00,03:00, 04:00
```

`str_replace()` will take them all out. `preg_replace` will let me limit how many I take out but will not let me take out all but 1. Do I need to write my own function for this? Is there already graceful solution?

Comment: You like to remove all am and pm string in array, correct ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, it keeps just the first am/pm string like you want it:

```
$timeSlots = array(
    "10:00 am",
    "11:00 am",
    "12:00 pm",
    "01:00 pm",
    "02:00 pm",
    "03:00 pm",
    "04:00 pm"
);

$foundAm = false;
$foundPm = false;

foreach( $timeSlots as $index => $timeSlot ) {
    if( strpos( $timeSlot, "am" ) !== false && $foundAm === false ) {
            $foundAm = true;
            continue;
    } else if( strpos( $timeSlot, "pm" ) !== false && $foundPm === false ) {
            $foundPm = true;
            continue;
    }

     $timeSlots[$index] = trim( str_replace( array( "am", "pm" ) , "", $timeSlot ) );
}

echo "<pre>";
var_dump( $timeSlots );

echo implode( ",", $timeSlots );
```

OUTPUT:

```
array(7) {
  [0]=>
  string(8) "10:00 am"
  [1]=>
  string(5) "11:00"
  [2]=>
  string(8) "12:00 pm"
  [3]=>
  string(5) "01:00"
  [4]=>
  string(5) "02:00"
  [5]=>
  string(5) "03:00"
  [6]=>
  string(5) "04:00"
}

10:00 am, 11:00, 12:00 pm, 01:00, 02:00, 03:00, 04:00
```

Comment: @CraigTucker glad to hear :)

Answer (score 0):

If its an array something like this could work I guess (Only if no keys are set ofcourse or if you know the first key)

```
$times = array('10:00 am','11:00 am','12:00 pm','01:00 pm','02:00 pm','03:00 pm','04:00 pm');
foreach($times as $key => $time){
    if($key != 0){
        $search = array(" am", " pm");
        $times[$key] = str_replace($search, "", $time);
    }
    //So if the key is 0 (The first element) continue, else remove the am/pm
}
```